# ¿Como quitar fondo negro al rotar imagen Python?

Tags: python, opencv

Estoy intentando rotar una imagen. El problema es que cuando lo giro sale un fondo negro en la foto.

Así es como giro la imagen, con la libreria math. También hago uso de OpenCv.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import math
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('LetraA.png', 0)
cv.imshow('Hola', img)
print("1 " + str (img [10,10]))
for x in range(img.shape [0]):
    for y in range (img.shape[1]):
        if img[x,y] < 200:
            img[x,y] = 0
        else:
            img[x,y] = 255

print ("2 " + str(img[10,10]))

h,w = img.shape[:2]

img2 = np.zeros((h*2, w*2), dtype = 'uint8')
for i in range (h):
    for j in range(w):
        img2[int(i*math.cos(math.radians(30))+30-j*math.sin(math.radians(30))), int (i*math.sin(math.radians(30))+j*math.cos(math.radians(30)))] = img[i,j]
        fff = Image.new('RGBA', img2.size, (255,)*4)
        
cv.imshow('imagen1', img)
cv.imshow('imagen2', img2)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Así es como realiza el giro:

[image: Imagen rotada]

Comment: Te serviría una respuesta en la cual, en lugar de usar un array numpy, convierta dicho array en un objeto Image del modulo Pillow?

Comment: Lo logre solucionar intercambiando la binarización en lugar de poner fondo blanco, letra negra, binarice a la inversa, así al rotar quedo completamente sin ruido, en caso de requerirlo con fondo blanco, letra negra, únicamente requeriría aplicar de nuevo la binarización a la inversa, no logre encontrar otra solución, pero con eso funciono.